# Import aws-amplify in Ionic2

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, aws-amplify

#### OverView

I develop an ionic mobile app with Visual Studio.
When I added import statement in src/app/main.ts, my app got not working and didn't render expected page.
Please tell me how to solve this.

I published my app to github.
[link to my github page](https://github.com/gilyoshiki/SampleProject)

#### Process of my app not working

1. I installed aws-amplify by npm command.

   `$ npm install aws-amplify --save`
2. I selected "Ionic 2 - Tabs" template and created new a project.
   [Visual Stido "Ionic 2 - Tabs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuYdS.png)
3. I added import statement in src/app/main.ts.

   `import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';`
4. My app got not working.

#### Error messages and ScreenShots

JavaScript Console shows messages below.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.css
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills.js
```

My app is expected to render the page below.

[expected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoInz.png)

But it rendered the page below.

[unexpected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IP1RP.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the error it doesn't look like from aws-amplify. How about first try remove import from aws-amplify?

It more like the visual studio template has problem. I just tried command line it works fine.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp
ionic serve
```

Here is an aws starter template maybe you could try follow.

https://github.com/ionic-team/starters/tree/master/ionic-angular/official/aws